# mutating table with this trigger oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Use Oracle database and need to store all rows in lower case. All `INSERT`and `UPDATE` should insert and update rows with lower case data. I wrote a trigger to do it. Read a lot of about table mutation with triggers.Very confused, will this code raise mutate error or not. Please, write here, if it will.

```
create or replace trigger employee_name
before update or insert on employee
for each row
begin
/* convert character values to lower case */
:new.lastname := lower( :new.lastname );
:new.firstname :=lower( :new.firstname );
end;
/
```

Comment: Trying to understand but maybe this link is useful http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936

Answer (score 3):

The trigger will *not* raise a mutating table error as you're not selecting from the table your trigger is on; you're only reassigning values, which is what triggers are designed to do.

It's worth noting that this can also be accomplished with a CHECK constraint, which will force everyone updating or inserting into the table to lower case everything:

```
alter table employee_name 
  add constraint chk_emp_name_lastname 
      check ( lastname = lower(lastname) )
```

Whilst this will increase update/insert times (not necessarily more than using a trigger) it *doesn't* silently change data being entered but instead complains that the data is incorrect. This is sometimes a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

this code not raise exception
because you not try select from table which trigger executing

Answer (score 0):

This should not raise any errors. Mutate errors occur when you read (or modify) some other rows from `BEFORE` trigger.

NOTE: there are situations where `BEFORE` trigger is fired more that once for the SAME row. 
In order to guarantee consistency Oracle would have to justify, that your trigger body is "idempotent": e.i. each execution on the same input gives the same result.